# python django how to send parameters to website in Post request

Tags: python, css, django

I am working on building a website with python Django. I want to do the following project.

First, I get the input values from the website. Then I use the input values to produce a plot and save it in one place of the server. After that, I want to send the location of the plot back to the website.

My codes are given below

In views.py

from django.shortcuts import render
import trip.forms

```
#First define to Django form.Forms
    form_class = trip.forms.AdHocTripReportRequestForm   
    graphurl_form=trip.forms.Graphurl

    #Then define a "get" function
        def get(self, request):
            encoded_cabinets, id_dirserved = self._encoded_page_precache()
            ctx = {
               'CABINETS': encoded_cabinets,
                'ID_DIRSERVED': id_dirserved,
                'form': self.form_class(),
                'graph': self.graphurl_form(),
              }
             # add adhoc settings
             profile = get_profile(request.user)
             if profile:
                 ctx.update(defaults=profile.get_settings('adhoctrip'))
             context = RequestContext(request, ctx)
             return render_to_response("adhoc-trip.html", context)


    #after that, there is a post function
         def post(self, request):
              #1) read the input values
             form = self.form_class(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid(request.user):
                 # update adhoc settings
                 profile = get_profile(request.user)
                 if profile:
                     settings_form = DateRangeDowEmailForm(request.POST)
                     if settings_form.is_valid():
                         profile.set_settings('adhoctrip', settings_form.cleaned_data)
                         profile.save()

                 # 2) some functions to get the link string
                     graphurl=trip.tasks.TripReportTask().delay(trr, recipients, server, save_as, trr1)

                 # 3) set this information to the html file
                     graphurl_form_tmp=trip.forms.Graphurl(request.POST or 
                                None, initial={'name': graphurl})
                     return render(request, "adhoc-trip.html", 
                                {'graph' : graphurl_form_tmp,})
```

In the adhop-trip.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var TripButtonBase = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(options) {
            options = options || {};
            this.waypoints = options.waypoints;
            this.dateInput = options.dateInput;
            this.corridorType = options.corridorType;
            this.compareYear=options.compareYear;
            this.errorList = options.errorList;
            this.omitList = options.omitList;
        },
        params: function() {
            // short-term fix to "is endpoint unchecked?" while new trip interface is completed
            try {
                var omittedLoopgroupIds = this.omitList.getOmitList();
            } catch(err) {
                alert("I'm sorry, but both trip endpoints must be checked in the Route Editor/Data Quality tab or no travel times can be calculated.
                return;
            }
            // end fix

            return _.extend(this.waypoints.params(), this.dateInput.params(),
                {omittedLoopgroupIds: omittedLoopgroupIds, corridorType: this.corridorType.val(), compareYear: this.compareYear.val()});
        }
    });

    var EmailTripButton = TripButtonBase.extend({
    // Request an adhoc trip report
    post: function() {
        var data = this.params();
        data.recipientEmail = $('#recipientEmail').val();
        var url = siteUrl('trip/adhoc-trip/');

        $.ajax(url, {
            context: this,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true, // serialize nested arrays with identical keys e.g., b=1&b=2&b=3
            type: "POST",
            success: this.postSuccess,
            error: this.postError,
        });
    },
    postSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("Trip will be emailed to you shortly");
        this.errorList.reset();
    },
    postError: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        switch (jqXHR.statusText) {
        case "BAD REQUEST":
            var errInfo = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            this.errorList.reset(errorInfoToErrors(errInfo));
            break;
        default:
            alert("Error in submitting trip");
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            break;
        }
    },
});
{% endblock script %}
```

Once I add the last line in the views.py (return render ...), the system will trigger the postError function, instead of the postSuccess function.

Any commends and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Even if you don't think the error message is useful, it might be helpful to include that stack trace.

Comment: @NathanHinchey Thanks for your reply, I have added more details about the problem in the post. It seems that it is related to the communication between Django and java by ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Please always include the full stack trace. It makes it much easier to pinpoint the actual error.

Without it I can only make guesses. Some ideas that come to mind:

1. The indentation for the code after the last comment seems off. If it's like that in the actual file, that would likely an error
2. Make sure you are importing everything that your program is using. For example, make sure
   'from django.shortcuts import render' 
   Is somewhere in your file.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. The error is not because of indentation. I believe. As your mentioned, I added the package which I used in the header

Comment: @DongHui did that fix it? If not, could you post the full stack trace in an edit to your original post? I think I would be able to answer your question better if I had that. Just in case you're unfamiliar with the wording, by full stack trace I mean the entire error message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have added more details about the problem in the post. It seems that it is related to the communication between Django and java by ajax.